# How to send an image as direct message with twitter in android?

Tags: android, image, twitter, sendmessage

I want to send an image with text to a follower using twitter4j. I am able to send a direct message like this:

```
twitter.sendDirectMessage(twitterID, message);
```

Now, I can't figure out how to send an image as direct message. I did this for posting a tweet, which works:

```
StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
            status.setMedia(pathOfTheFileToSend);
            twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

So is it possible to send a image as direct message in twitter with the library twitter4j?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it's worth noting what `Twitter4j` does. It provides a good abstraction and bindings to Twitter's REST API in Java.

If you look at Twitter's [Direct Message Endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/direct_messages/new) you will see that it does **not** currently provide a way to "attach" an image when sending a direct message.

This has been confirmed at [Twitter Developers forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/uploading-images-in-dms/12317) before:

> We have no announced plans yet for providing a media upload endpoint
>   for direct messages.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to attach an image to a DM that works for me in my java project, using the following code:

```
...
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
//Get the User ID from the Screen Name
User user = twitter.showUser("screenName"); //@Hec_KuFlow for example
long userId = user.getId();
//The message to send
String message = "Hi! this is the message";
//Upload the file and get the ID
File imageFile = new File("C:\\demo\\picture.png");
long[] mediaIds = new long[1];
UploadedMedia media = twitter.uploadMedia(imageFile);
mediaIds[0] = media.getMediaId();

DirectMessage directMessage = twitter.directMessages().sendDirectMessage(userId, message, mediaIds[0]) throws TwitterException;
```

...

Answer (score -1):

Use following code to send an image with text

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

   configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key));

     configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));

configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(LoginActivity.getAccessToken((context)));

configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(LoginActivity.getAccessTokenSecret(context));

Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);

status.setMedia(file); // set the image to be uploaded here.

twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

For details explanation check this [tutorial](https://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/tutorial-on-uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitter4j/).

Comment: this, post a tweet,not a direct message.

Answer (score -2):

```
public void tweetPicture(File file, String message) throws Exception  {

  try{

    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
    status.setMedia(file);
    mTwitter.updateStatus(status);}

    catch(TwitterException e){
        Log.d("TAG", "Pic Uploading error" + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}
```

OR you can [refer this](https://github.com/khetiyachintan/Android-Twitter-Example/blob/master/src/chintan/khetiya/android/Twitter_sharing/MainActivity.java)

Comment: this, post a tweet,like above,not a direct message.

Comment: yes and its works for me.. and i have give you one link also so you can see over there also

Comment: i know how to post an image as tweet. But i don't know how to send a direct message, have you read my question?